# Pandas, filter by count

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

I'm trying to filter a dataframe by the number of occurrences for `id`.

```
id    date
1     2018-05-06
1     2018-05-08
1     2018-05-11
2     2018-06-02
2     2018-06-16
3     2018-06-04
3     2018-06-09
4     2018-06-06
4     2018-06-11
4     2018-06-17
```

I want to filter for the `id` values that have 3 occurrences, so the resulting filtered dataframe should look like this:

```
id    date
1     2018-05-06
1     2018-05-08
1     2018-05-11
4     2018-06-06
4     2018-06-11
4     2018-06-17
```

I previously had tried using the following code, which I got from another StackOverflow post. The code worked at first, but when I used it about a half hour later, it gave me the error "lambda cannot contain assignment":

```
graphview3 = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x['id'].count()=3)
```

I don't know why this code previously worked and is now giving me this error. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graphview3 = df.loc[df['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts()) == 3]
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to learn how to make faster, more efficient code. Is this method faster than the len() and transform() methods below?

Comment: On my machine, mine is 2.14ms, from Jezrael are 2.77 & 2.3 . I think you should time it on your machine for your complete dataframe & then decide.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need compare length of each group:

```
graphview3 = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3)
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
graphview3 = df[df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('size') == 3]
print (graphview3)
   id        date
0   1  2018-05-06
1   1  2018-05-08
2   1  2018-05-11
7   4  2018-06-06
8   4  2018-06-11
9   4  2018-06-17
```

In your solution need double `==` for compare, also more common [`Series.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html) is used for count values with exclude `NaN`s (but here it working nice, because `groupby` by default drop rows with `NaN`s in `id`):

```
graphview3 = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x['id'].count()==3)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why the code I used before worked at one point and then gave me the "lambda cannot contain assignment" error?"

Comment: @bbk611 - sure, there is only one `=` in `=3`, but need `==3`

Comment: That was stupid of me. Didn't realize it was a Boolean. Thank you.